# How to use `controllers.Default.redirect` in Play 2.4 and `InjectedRoutesGenerator`

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

If I try to use `controllers.Default.redirect(to = "/foo/bar")` in my `routes` file with `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` enabled in my `build.sbt` file, I get the compilation error

```
type Default is not a member of package controllers
```

With this new injected routes feature in Play 2.4 is there still a way to use handlers defined in static objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there's not. Default should be made a class so it can be used from an injected router, with a companion object that extends it so it can still be used from the static router. Please raise an issue in the Play issue tracker, or better, submit a pull request to fix this.